# Conectar-se ao banco de dados via console do navegador

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, console

Eu tenho uma aplicação em JS que roda via console do navegador. Gostaria de saber quais as possibilidades de enviar e receber dados via mysql pelo Console.

Não sei também se é possível.

Tentei algo, mas não funcionou. Exemplo:

```
lastMsg = "Message received";   // recebe a msg
var mysql = require('mysql'); // 

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "yourusername",
    password: "yourpassword",
    database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    var sql = "INSERT INTO mensagens (textomsg) VALUES (lastMsg)";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 record inserted");
    });
});
```

Eu recebo o seguinte erro no console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Console do navegador + mysql não vai funcionar, você pode usar o localStorage se quiser rodar no browser ou uma api para o servidor.

Comment: Qual o caminho para uma API?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta

Comment: Qual o melhor caminho pra fazer uma API neste caso por console

Comment: Você não faz uma API no console do navegador, vai ser um servidor que provê as informações, daí pela interface você pode fazer as requisições para a API, de qualquer forma, não tem um jeito único/simples de fazer isso.